# Material Button Toggle Group doesn't work (not showing)

Tags: android, material-components-android

I have in gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
```

Then my layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
        android:id="@+id/toggle_button_group"
        id="@+id/toggleBtnGroup"
        android:layout_width="129dp"
        android:layout_height="23dp"
        app:checkedButton="@+id/leftAlign"
        app:singleSelection="true">

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
            id="@+id/leftAlign"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Left" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
            id="@+id/centerAlign"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Center" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
            id="@+id/rightAlign"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Right" />

    </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

But when I set to Design mode on the layout - there is just a square with no buttons.

[image]

Anybody knows why? I am using Arctic Fox Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

set height wrap_content

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
    android:id="@+id/toggle_button_group"
    id="@+id/toggleBtnGroup"
    android:layout_width="129dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:checkedButton="@+id/leftAlign"
    app:singleSelection="true">
</com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).